# Ball on a slope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-kinematics

I have a lab report, but I can not write it in a correct way.

The lab experiment was about a ball rolling on a slope, I have a height of the slope, the distance, and the time in which the ball spent to reach the end of the slope.  I have data from 4 trials.

My question is: How I can know the gravity is constant in all these trials, and which equation do I need to use?

Comment: can you share with us the result of this experiment? i.e. the 4 time values?

Comment: It seems to me that you want to find the moment of inertia and assume that the gravity is constant.

Comment: How the hell is this off topic?

Answer (score 4):

For a ball rolling  down a  ramp, using the KE and PE, you can find that it will be

$$ mgh = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 + \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2 $$

Use $v = r\omega$ and $I = 2/5 \space mr^2 $ and you get $a = 5/7 \space g \space sin\theta$ ( $\theta$ is the angle of incline).

Do not forget to include the errors in your measurements both in distance and in time, so for each measurement, you will get a different value of $g$ depending on the accuracy of your measurement

Comment: The question is about an object rolling down a slope, so no free fall.

Comment: Assuming the balls start from rest, you would use $d = \frac{1}{2} a t^2$ to tease out the acceleration, and compare it with the expected. Assuming different times, you could plot $d$ vs $t^2$ and use the ol' line o' best fit.